# How to find strings of contiguous numbers that are the same

Tags: r

I have the following data frame:

```
A <- c(0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1)
B <- c(1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0)
C <- c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0)
df <- data.frame(A, B, C)
> df
   A B C
1  0 1 0
2  1 1 0
3  1 1 0
4  1 1 0
5  1 0 0
6  0 0 1
7  0 0 1
8  1 0 1
9  1 0 1
10 1 1 1
11 0 1 1
12 0 1 1
13 1 1 0
14 1 1 0
15 1 0 0
16 1 0 0
```

I would like to write a code to know how many strings of consecutive 1s are in each column. I would like the output to be in the form of a dataframe:

```
> Number_of_Strings_of_Consecutive_Ones
  A B C
1 3 2 1
```

How can I do this? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `rle`

```
sapply(df, function(x) sum(rle(x)$values == 1))
#A B C
#3 2 1
```